# SASS : Check if a variable is a map

Tags: sass, sass-maps

Is there something like `is-map($some_variable)` in SASS?

I have tried looking into the documentation but there is none there.

Answer (score 22):

You can implement it with the `type-of` function, like this one:

```
@function is-map($var){
  @return type-of($var) == 'map';
}
```

Comment: And if $var is map and you need to check if `map-get($var, $key)` is map?

Comment: map-get($var, $key) == 'map'